# How to ignore the glogin file in SQLPLUS

Tags: sqlplus

I use a glogin file with sqlplus, it works fine but i have some scripts that are getting the variables of the file and i dont want to.

Is there a parameter in the sqlplus conexion maybe to ignore the glogin file?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do not set the parameters explicitly in scripts?

Comment: I tried that but i dont know the default parameters of sqlplus this is what we set inm the glogin, maybe revert the changes in every SQL is the way:


set lines 200 pages 5000 timing on time on
alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
define _editor=vi
set sqlprompt '_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER SQL>'

Comment: I see. The other way is to temporary rename the `glogin` file before exec the script and rename it back. This will work quite well if you do not mix (in time) these batches and interactive sessions.

Comment: I thought about that but there are a lot of SQL scripts and maybe they overlap or something, i will try if this works, thanks for your time do.